# Any idea how to implement a view that only brings the values ​you've searched?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm putting together a search page that uses a DB with more than 1000,000 registries. Any idea how to implement a view that only brings the values ​​you've searched? I've been able to do this with a smaller DB (300), however, it loads all the registries in the view before searching. I need it to return nothing if the search field is empty.

(Spring MVC, JPA, Hibernate and Thymeleaf).

````
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<Alarme> filtrar(Alarme filtro, Pageable pageable) {

        int paginaatual = pageable.getPageNumber();
        int totalRegistrosPorPagina = pageable.getPageSize();
        int primeiroRegistro = paginaatual * totalRegistrosPorPagina;

        Criteria criteria = manager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Alarme.class);
        criteria.setFirstResult(primeiroRegistro);
        criteria.setMaxResults(totalRegistrosPorPagina);

        Sort sort = pageable.getSort();
        System.out.println(">>> sort: " + sort);
        if (sort != null) {
            Sort.Order order = sort.iterator().next();
            String property = order.getProperty();
            criteria.addOrder(order.isAscending() ? Order.asc(property) : Order.desc(property));
        }

        adicionarFiltro(filtro, criteria);

        return new PageImpl<>(criteria.list(), pageable, total(filtro));
    }

    private Long total(Alarme filtro) {
        Criteria criteria = manager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Alarme.class);
        adicionarFiltro(filtro, criteria);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
        return (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }

    private void adicionarFiltro(Alarme filtro, Criteria criteria) {
        if(filtro != null){
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getIncidente())){
                criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("incidente", filtro.getIncidente(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
            }
        }

        if(filtro != null){
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getSite())){
                criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("site", filtro.getSite(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
            }
        }
    }

}```
````

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to load all the data in front when the data is big.Can you perform a backend query  when the search field loses focus?

Comment: No. It's what I need to do. Can you show me a example?